# PHP function on SQL selectee

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to perform a specific PHP function on data that is being returned by a database query, at the very moment this query is still running?

Let's say we are in some class and we have the following pseudo SQL which should return a couple of rows:

```
$results = $this->db->query("SELECT PHP_function(column), column 2 FROM table")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`PHP_function` could be `json_decode` for example.

Or is this not possible and would it require an additional loop on the results in order to do such a thing?

Comment: Why would you want to do that at query time, and not later on?

Comment: Why do you need it as the query is running? What's wrong with looping through the data afterwards?

Comment: If you need functionality the RDBMS doesn't already provide (it provides a lot), you may need a [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html)

Comment: It's an additional loop.

Comment: for me seems more legit: `return php_function($row['column']);` or even not returning, but using it somewhere inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [manual page for the very function you're using](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1025) contains an example

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I can force the arguments of PDO::FETCH_FUNC to be associative? PDO::FETCH_ASSOC does not achieve this. This is of course because arguments can't really be associative, thus receiving a numerically indexed array from `func_get_args` is natural behaviour. I would instead rather have one argument passed to the function of FETCH_FUNC, which would be an indexed array of the columns returned from the database query.

Comment: I wouldn't waste time with research but rather use fetch() in a while loop instead of fetchAll() and apply whatever complex logic in this loop.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  SQL engine (mysql or any other) is a separate application.  PHP can communicate with it, send queries and receive data.  Depending on what you want to do in that custom function, you may be able to write a custom function in mysql to do the same thing.

Have a look at [`create function` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for info on how to do that.

Comment: Before PDO I used to be able to perform any function in the while loop `($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))` after the query, so I hoped there was some way to access this loop. I guess it's in the PDO `fetchAll` method. Edit: hadn't seen the answer of YCS, but StackoverFlow is now warning me to not accept anything within the next six minutes..

Comment: @user2180613 This is not the same as you're asking.  You can still do the loop, but you cannot use php function in the select clause.

Comment: I know it is not possible to mix the functions of two languages. See my question's first sentence.

Comment: @user2180613 You asked whether it's possible to execute a function on a query when it's still running - and the answer is "no".  When you're retrieving the data in a loop, the query has completed, it's not running any more.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the problem with this?

```
<?php
    foreach($results as $key=>$res){
        $results[$key]['column'] = PHP_function($res['column']);
    }
```

Beside that MySQL has some useful [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html) included already, so maybe that one you need is usable right in the query

Answer (score 0):

As i know it's not possible to achieve php manipulation while query running , you need to take  result and then loop aur use predefined function from